# How to filter the specific entries within a with a specific pattern over certain value?

Tags: python, regex, search, filtering

I have a data file containing the following information: 
I am interested to retrieve only the entries where the pattern

**len:XXXX** is greater than 200

> TY_DN106_c0_g2::TY_DN106_c0_g2_i1::g.1::m.1 type:internal **len:123** gc:universal TY_DN106_c0_g2_i1:1-366(+)
>   TY_DN106_c0_g2::TY_DN106_c0_g2_i1::g.2::m.2 type:internal **len:213** gc:universal TY_DN106_c0_g2_i1:366-1(-)
>   TY_DN108_c0_g1::TY_DN108_c0_g1_i1::g.3::m.3 type:5partial **len:513** gc:universal TY_DN108_c0_g1_i1:3-341(+)

How could I do it in Python or other scripting language??

Comment: what is input format? You need to get entire line that contains len:xxx > 200?

Comment: its the text file and I need all the entries that have the lenxxx>200

Comment: text is in one line or separated line by line? By entry you mean text from.. to ... ?

Comment: each entry is separated by a new line and every entry starts with "TY"

Comment: @TCFPHCDG can you provide an example of what exactly are you trying to get?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `len:([2-9]\d{2}|[1-9]\d{3,})` regex to get the matches you need.

If you want to match the whole line, use this: `^.*len:([2-9]\d\d|[1-9]\d{3,}).*$`.

---

#### Regex explanation

The first part of the expression: `len:` matches the characters *'len:'* literally.

After, in the first capturing group we have 2 alternatives.

The first option: `[2-9]\d{2}` matches a number between 2 and 9, followed by any two-digit number, thus covering all the numbers from 200 to 999.

The second option: `[1-9]\d{3,}` matches all the characters starting with the digits 1 to 9 and followed by 3 other digits, thus covering all integers from 1000 to inf, leaving out the numerical characters starting with 0s.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
import re


file_path = 'file.txt'
pattern = r'len:\d{3,}'

with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if re.search(pattern, line):
            if int(re.search(pattern, line)[0].split(':')[1]) > 200:
                print(line)
```

If you wont to write result to the new file, try this:

```
import re


file_path = 'file.txt'
new_file_path = 'new_file.txt'
pattern = r'len:\d{3,}'

with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f1:
    with open(new_file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f2:
        for line in f1.readlines():
            if re.search(pattern, line):
                if int(re.search(pattern, line)[0].split(':')[1]) > 200:
                    f2.write(line)
```

Here is an example with regex by @Henry Harutyunyan:

```
import re


file_path = 'file.txt'
pattern = r'len:([2-9]\d{2}|[1-9]\d{3,})'

with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f1:
    for line in f1.readlines():
        if re.search(pattern, line):
            print(line)
```

Comment: Could to it with single regex without the need for splitting and checking

Comment: Yep, you can take regex by @HenryHarutyunyan

Comment: It will just print the first occurrence of the "pattern" and close the file.

Comment: What If we need to find all the lines with this pattern

Comment: import re

infile = "/Users/tcfh/Desktop/test_length_filter"
outfile="/Users/tcfh/Desktop/test_length_filter_out"

pat = r'len:([2-9]\d{2} | [1-9]\d{3,})'

with open(infile, 'r') as f1, open(outfile, 'w') as f2:
        for seqhead in (f1):
                if re.search(pat, seqhead):
                        seqhd = seqhead
                        seq= (next(f1, '').strip())

                        blc = (seqhd + seq)
                        f2.write (blc)

Answer (score 1):

For data in you data.txt file like this:

```
TY_DN106_c0_g2::TY_DN106_c0_g2_i1::g.1::m.1 type:internal len:123 gc:universal
TY_DN106_c0_g2_i1:1-366(+)
TY_DN106_c0_g2::TY_DN106_c0_g2_i1::g.2::m.2 type:internal len:213 gc:universal
TY_DN106_c0_g2_i1:366-1(-)
TY_DN108_c0_g1::TY_DN108_c0_g1_i1::g.3::m.3 type:5partial len:513 gc:universal
TY_DN108_c0_g1_i1:3-341(+)
```

use regex:
1. find proper line
2. extract number
3. compare number with condition

```
import re

data = open('data.txt', 'r').readlines()

for line in data:
    proper_row = re.findall('len:\d+', line.strip())
    if len(proper_row) > 0:
        number = re.findall('\d+', proper_row[0])[0]
        if int(number) > 200:
            print(line.strip())
```

Output:

```
TY_DN106_c0_g2::TY_DN106_c0_g2_i1::g.2::m.2 type:internal len:213 gc:universal
TY_DN108_c0_g1::TY_DN108_c0_g1_i1::g.3::m.3 type:5partial len:513 gc:universal
```